# How can I know if a game from an NTSC region can be run on a PAL console?

Tags: xbox-360, region-lock

On a PAL xbox system - I can run some NTSC games. Is there a way to know which NTSC game will run on the PAL console just by its cover?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.
But you can look up at places like [this](http://forum.xbox-sky.cc/xbox360_regional_compatibility_guide/)